# Menu Button in Cocos2d

Tags: ios6, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.5

Im trying to make the play button on the main menu of my game in Cocos2d which is an image file. I set up the sprite as playButton with the image Play Button.png. When I ran the app it gave me an error that the "itemFromNormalSprite:selectedSprite:target:selector." is deprecated. Anybody have a solution to this problem? Here is my code:

```
CCMenuItem *playGameButton = [CCMenuItemSprite itemFromNormalSprite:playButton selectedSprite:playButton target:self selector:@selector(buttonTapped:)];
    CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:playGameButton, nil];
    menu.position = ccp(size.width/2, size.height/1.5);
    [self addChild:menu z:5];
```

Comment: look in ccDeprecated.m what it needs to be replaced with

Comment: Are all the things in ccDeprecated.m deprecated code? Or does it actually have replacements for the deprecated code?

Comment: c'mon @MyersAppDevelopment ... ure one click or one ^F away from the answer.

Comment: I ended up just doing CCMenuItemImage. I get it now thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    CCMenuItem *playGameButton = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:playButton selectedImage:playButton disabledImage:disabledPlayButton target:self selector:@selector(buttonTapped:)];
    CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:playGameButton, nil];
    menu.position = ccp(size.width/2, size.height/1.5);
    [self addChild:menu z:5];
```